# Some of these codes don't run

Tags: c++

i'm a beginner at C++ and i tried to make a script for a Trinity Core World of Warcraft private server but it seems that some of the codes ran successfully and the others are escaped for unknown reason..

here's the code

```
#include "ScriptPCH.h"
#include "DisableMgr.h"

class LearnSpellsOnLevelUp : public PlayerScript 
{
public:
    LearnSpellsOnLevelUp()
        : PlayerScript("LearnSpellsOnLevelUp"){};

    void OnLevelChanged(Player* player, uint8 oldLevel)
    {
        if (player->getClass() == 3 && player->getLevel() >= 12) // ran
        {
            if (player->HasSpell(23356)) // ran
                return; // ran
            else // ran
                player->LearnSpell(23356, false); // ran
            player->GetSession()->SendAreaTriggerMessage("|cff00FF00You Learnt new Spell [Taming Lesson]!|r"); // ran
        }

        if (player->getClass() == 9) // Warlock  // ran
        {
            if (player->getLevel() >= 2) // ran
            {
                if (player->HasSpell(44163)) // ran
                    return;
                else
                    player->LearnSpell(44163, false); // ran
                player->GetSession()->SendAreaTriggerMessage("|cff00FF00You Learnt new Spell [Summon Imp]!|r"); // ran
            }
            else if (player->getLevel() >= 10) 
            {
                if (player->HasSpell(25112))
                    return;
                else
                    player->LearnSpell(25112, false);
                player->GetSession()->SendAreaTriggerMessage("|cff00FF00You Learnt new Spell [Summon Voidwalker]!|r");
            }
            else if (player->getLevel() >= 20) 
            {
                if (player->HasSpell(712))
                    return;
                else
                    player->LearnSpell(712, false);
                player->GetSession()->SendAreaTriggerMessage("|cff00FF00You Learnt new Spell [Summon Succubus]!|r");
            }
            else if (player->getLevel() >= 30)
            {
                if (player->HasSpell(691))
                    return;
                else
                    player->LearnSpell(691, false);
                player->GetSession()->SendAreaTriggerMessage("|cff00FF00You Learnt new Spell [Summon Felhunter]!|r");
            }
            else
                return;
        }
    }
};

void AddSC_LearnSpellsOnLevelUp()
{
    new LearnSpellsOnLevelUp();
}
```

i wrote next to the codes that ran successfully // ran

Comment: Maybe you have no Warlock  with level >= 10.  | Debugger is your friend

Comment: So the next thing you need to learn about is how to use your debugger.  Take a look at this link https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: IMHO, you don't have to use `else if` in your case. Indeed, 32 is greater than 2, so you enter in first condition. Because you use `else if` for other case, it's normal that you never enter in it. Try by replacing `else if` by a simple `if`

Comment: Also, learn how to create function, you have a lot of duplication code (except values)

Comment: Your title is not going to be useful for a future visitor/searcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay close attention to the order of your `getLevel` conditions.

```
if (player->getLevel() >= 2)
{
}
// Here, it's certain that the level is < 2, since it wasn't >= 2.
// Thus, none of these following tests will be true.
else if (player->getLevel() >= 10)
{
}
else if (player->getLevel() >= 20)
{
}
else if (player->getLevel() >= 30)
{
}
else
    return;
```

You should test the levels starting with the greatest one and work your way donwnward.

```
if (player->getLevel() >= 30)
{
}
// The level is less than 30. Is it greater than 20?
else if (player->getLevel() >= 20)
{
}
// The level is less than 20. Is it greater than 10?
else if (player->getLevel() >= 10)
{
}
// The level is less than 10. Is it greater than 2?
else if (player->getLevel() >= 2)
{
}
else
    return;
```

Comment: Worked! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is simply a logic bug. Let's look at this statement:

`if (player->getLevel() >= 2) // ran`   - ok so far

And now a lot of this:

`else if (player->getLevel() >= 10)`    - and others (comparing with 20, 30)

Now suppose your 'player' has 15 level - looks like the *intent* was to run the second `if` block (e.g. where you compare with `>= 10`)

But there is a problem: if the level is 15 then *everytime* only the *first* `if`-block is executed (because obviously 15 >= 2).

**Solution:** compare to range, like this:

```
if ((player->getLevel() >= 2) && (player->getLevel() < 10))
...
else if ((player->getLevel() >= 10) && (player->getLevel() < 20))
...
```

And so on.

Comment: I got it now, thank you